# How to check if a list element contains a regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a file with information about sequences. Every sequence has some lines. The sequences are separated by five white lines. I want to change the file into a list, and split it by 5 newlines. So that I have a list, with every sequence as one element. Then I want to remove the sequences that not contain the regular expression. At the end, I want a list, with only the sequences that contain the regex.

Now I have this. Can anyone help me further?

```
import re
def main():
    ReadFile()
    file = open ("filename.txt", "r")
    CreateList(file, data)
    RegEx(file, data)

def ReadFile()
    try:
        file = open ("filename.txt", "r")
    except IOError:
        print ("Can't open the file")
    except:
        print ("Something went wrong.")

def CreateList(file, data)
    data = file.readlines()
    data = data.split('\n\n\n\n\n')

def RegEx(file, data)
    regex = ("[AG].{4}GK[ST]") 
    for element in data:
        if regex not in element: 
            data.remove(element) 
    print (data) 

main()
```

File looks like:

```
Hits for PS00017|ATP_GTP_A (pattern) ATP/GTP-binding site motif A (P-loop) :  [occurs frequently]
   Pattern: [AG]-x(4)-G-K-[ST]
   Approximate number of expected random matches in ~ 100'000 sequences (50'000'000 residues): 3371


>sp|Q6GZX2|003R_FRG3G  (438 aa)
Uncharacterized protein 3R.  [Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3)]
MARPLLGKTSSVRRRLESLSACSIFFFLRKFCQKMASLVFLNSPVYQMSNILLTERRQVDRAMGGSDDDGVMVVALSPSD
FKTVLGSALLAVERDMVHVVPKYLQTPGILHDMLVLLTPIFGEALSVDMSGATDVMVQQIATAGFVDVDPLHSSVSWKDN
VSCPVALLAVSNAVRTMMGQPCQVTLIIDVGTQNILRDLVNLPVEMSGDLQVMAYTKDPLGKVPAVGVSVFDSGSVQKGD
AHSVGAPDGLVSFHTHPVSSAVELNYHAGWPSNVDMSSLLTMKNLMHVVVAEEGLWTMARTLSMQRLTKVLTDAEKDVMR
AAAFNLFLPLNELRVMGTKDSNNKSLKTYFEVFETFTIGALMKHSGVTPTAFVDRRWLDNTIYHMGFIPWGRDMRFVVEY
DLDGTNPFLNTVPTLMSVKRKAKIQEMFDNMVSRMVTS
      2 - 9:          ArpllGKT


>sp|Q6GZX1|004R_FRG3G  (60 aa)
Uncharacterized protein 004R.  [Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3)]
MNAKYDTDQGVGRMLFLGTIGLAVVVGGLMAYGYYYDGKTPSSGTSFHTASPSFSSRYRY
      33 - 40:        GyyydGKT


>sp|Q6GZW0|015R_FRG3G  (322 aa)
Uncharacterized protein 015R.  [Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3)]
MEQVPIKEMRLSDLRPNNKSIDTDLGGTKLVVIGKPGSGKSTLIKALLDSKRHIIPCAVVISGSEEANGFYKGVVPDLFI
YHQFSPSIIDRIHRRQVKAKAEMGSKKSWLLVVIDDCMDNAKMFNDKEVRALFKNGRHWNVLVVIANQYVMDLTPDLRSS
VDGVFLFRENNVTYRDKTYANFASVVPKKLYPTVMETVCQNYRCMFIDNTKATDNWHDSVFWYKAPYSKSAVAPFGARSY
WKYACSKTGEEMPAVFDNVKILGDLLLKELPEAGEALVTYGGKDGPSDNEDGPSDDEDGPSDDEEGLSKDGVSEYYQSDL
DD
      34 - 41:        GkpgsGKS',


>sp|P32234|128UP_DROME  (368 aa)
GTP-binding protein 128up.  [Drosophila melanogaster (Fruit fly)]
MSTILEKISAIESEMARTQKNKATSAHLGLLKAKLAKLRRELISPKGGGGGTGEAGFEVAKTGDARVGFVGFPSVGKSTL
LSNLAGVYSEVAAYEFTTLTTVPGCIKYKGAKIQLLDLPGIIEGAKDGKGRGRQVIAVARTCNLIFMVLDCLKPLGHKKL
LEHELEGFGIRLNKKPPNIYYKRKDKGGINLNSMVPQSELDTDLVKTILSEYKIHNADITLRYDATSDDLIDVIEGNRIY
IPCIYLLNKIDQISIEELDVIYKIPHCVPISAHHHWNFDDLLELMWEYLRLQRIYTKPKGQLPDYNSPVVLHNERTSIED
FCNKLHRSIAKEFKYALVWGSSVKHQPQKVGIEHVLNDEDVVQIVKKV
      71 - 78:        GfpsvGKS
```

Data it should be (but only proteins containing the RegEx):

```
['>sp|Q6GZX2|003R_FRG3G  (438 aa)
Uncharacterized protein 3R.  [Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3)]
MARPLLGKTSSVRRRLESLSACSIFFFLRKFCQKMASLVFLNSPVYQMSNILLTERRQVDRAMGGSDDDGVMVVALSPSD
FKTVLGSALLAVERDMVHVVPKYLQTPGILHDMLVLLTPIFGEALSVDMSGATDVMVQQIATAGFVDVDPLHSSVSWKDN
VSCPVALLAVSNAVRTMMGQPCQVTLIIDVGTQNILRDLVNLPVEMSGDLQVMAYTKDPLGKVPAVGVSVFDSGSVQKGD
AHSVGAPDGLVSFHTHPVSSAVELNYHAGWPSNVDMSSLLTMKNLMHVVVAEEGLWTMARTLSMQRLTKVLTDAEKDVMR
AAAFNLFLPLNELRVMGTKDSNNKSLKTYFEVFETFTIGALMKHSGVTPTAFVDRRWLDNTIYHMGFIPWGRDMRFVVEY
DLDGTNPFLNTVPTLMSVKRKAKIQEMFDNMVSRMVTS
      2 - 9:          ArpllGKT',


'>sp|Q6GZX1|004R_FRG3G  (60 aa)
Uncharacterized protein 004R.  [Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3)]
MNAKYDTDQGVGRMLFLGTIGLAVVVGGLMAYGYYYDGKTPSSGTSFHTASPSFSSRYRY
      33 - 40:        GyyydGKT',


'>sp|Q6GZW0|015R_FRG3G  (322 aa)
Uncharacterized protein 015R.  [Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3)]
MEQVPIKEMRLSDLRPNNKSIDTDLGGTKLVVIGKPGSGKSTLIKALLDSKRHIIPCAVVISGSEEANGFYKGVVPDLFI
YHQFSPSIIDRIHRRQVKAKAEMGSKKSWLLVVIDDCMDNAKMFNDKEVRALFKNGRHWNVLVVIANQYVMDLTPDLRSS
VDGVFLFRENNVTYRDKTYANFASVVPKKLYPTVMETVCQNYRCMFIDNTKATDNWHDSVFWYKAPYSKSAVAPFGARSY
WKYACSKTGEEMPAVFDNVKILGDLLLKELPEAGEALVTYGGKDGPSDNEDGPSDDEDGPSDDEEGLSKDGVSEYYQSDL
DD
      34 - 41:        GkpgsGKS',


'>sp|P32234|128UP_DROME  (368 aa)
GTP-binding protein 128up.  [Drosophila melanogaster (Fruit fly)]
MSTILEKISAIESEMARTQKNKATSAHLGLLKAKLAKLRRELISPKGGGGGTGEAGFEVAKTGDARVGFVGFPSVGKSTL
LSNLAGVYSEVAAYEFTTLTTVPGCIKYKGAKIQLLDLPGIIEGAKDGKGRGRQVIAVARTCNLIFMVLDCLKPLGHKKL
LEHELEGFGIRLNKKPPNIYYKRKDKGGINLNSMVPQSELDTDLVKTILSEYKIHNADITLRYDATSDDLIDVIEGNRIY
IPCIYLLNKIDQISIEELDVIYKIPHCVPISAHHHWNFDDLLELMWEYLRLQRIYTKPKGQLPDYNSPVVLHNERTSIED
FCNKLHRSIAKEFKYALVWGSSVKHQPQKVGIEHVLNDEDVVQIVKKV
      71 - 78:        GfpsvGKS']
```

Comment: Can you post what the file looks like and what you want your end result to look like

Comment: Now show what you want print(data) to look like

Comment: Edited too, but then only the proteins containg the RegEx.

Comment: Okay I'll have an answer up in a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
file = open("ploop.txt")
text = file.read()
file.close()

proteins = text.split("\n\n")[1:]
proteinsMatching = []
toWrite = "" 

for protein in proteins:
    if re.search(r"[AG].{4}GK[ST]", protein):
        proteinsMatching.append(protein)        


for protein in proteinsMatching:
    accensionCode = re.findall(r">sp\|(.{6})", protein)[0]
    organism = re.findall(r"\n.+?\[(.+?)\]", protein)[0]
    print(accensionCode, organism)
    toWrite += accensionCode + " " + organism + "\n"

f = open("results.txt", "w+")
f.write(toWrite)
f.close()

# Q6GZX2 Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3)
# Q6GZX1 Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3)
# Q6GZW0 Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3)
# P32234 Drosophila melanogaster (Fruit fly)
```

## updated (again) for new requirements

Regex1 (Splitting text file into list of proteins:) https://regex101.com/r/gU0gX5/1

Regex2 (Your regex showing that they all match) https://regex101.com/r/nZ0pD6/1

Comment: Thanks for this script! Now the regular expression works and I get the proteins containing this RE. But, after this, I must do something else with all the proteins containing the RE, so it should be in a list. (From every protein containing this RE, I must print the Accession Code (6 tokens after the >sp) and the organism (first info between the '()' in the second line). So, is it also possible with your script to make a list of the proteins? That makes it easier for later.

Comment: i'll fix it to do what you want, can you give me an example of what the first accession code should look like? Would the first accension token be: Q6GZX2

Comment: take a look now, I think that should give you what you are looking for as long as the format is always going to be exactly the same

Comment: Thanks so much! Yes indeed, the first accession code should be Q6GZX2. And the first organism/specie should be "isolate Goorha".

Comment: Okay I adedd one character, it now prints (isolate goorha) instead of (isolate goorha) (fv-3)

Comment: If this answers your question you can click the check mark to mark it as answered, otherwise let me know what else you need

Comment: Wauw thanks! It works for the first few proteins. But for the 7th one I get an error. (Screenshot: http://i67.tinypic.com/2nbytu1.png)

Comment: Can you post the whole file to http://pastebin.com/ or something, I was expecting them all to look like the first couple you posted

Comment: It's a fasta file, so I don't know how to open it on an other way with python. But I've made a smaller part of it with notepad, now it has more white lines, but the real fasta file is as in the first post. But this is a part of the .fa file: http://pastebin.com/Tt8Ye177. If you want a download link to the whole file, tell me!

Comment: If you want to open the file like text just change the extension from .fa to .txt. But if you could give me the download link to the real file that would be best. I can't test the program with this file because it's formatted completely different then the one you want to actually use

Comment: Okay, I've uploaded it, this is the real download link: http://www.filedropper.com/ploop

Comment: It fails on Replication protein 1a.  [Broad bean mottle virus] because it's looking for parenthesis because it's prints the name by looking inbetween parentheses, what would you like it to print for this case

Comment: Oh okay, uuhm, maybe something as 'Unknown'? Maybe it's unknown if there isn't a name given in the file.

Comment: Take a look now, since you don't always get parenthesis I've changed it to to use whatever is in the brackets as the organism name, the results are too big for console so I have it output the results to results.txt file

Comment: Does this work or do you want me to change it to name or "unknown"

Comment: Oh that not a must haha, it was just an idea. I'm gonna test it now! :)

Comment: Thank you so much!! Indeed, it works! Now I get the organism name and the accession code. Thanks so much!! I'll mark it as 'solved'!

Comment: Wait, I have one more thing, this only reads 999 proteins instead of all 1000, I'll edit the post to fix it in a sec

Comment: Okay it's updated, this version correctly reads all 1000, I changed the first regex to a split, ignoring the very first item since that's info about the file `Hits for PS00017|ATP_GTP_A (pattern) AT`